# How to call a value written in printf to another printf

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I am very new to programming.

I am trying to write a program that will call the price of fruit from an array. But I would like the code to also write the name of the fruit before writing the price like. If I type 2, how do make the output be "Orange price : 10" rather than just price : 10.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int a[3] = { 5,10,15 };
    printf("1) Apple");
    printf("2) Orange");
    printf("3) grape");

    while (1) {

        printf("Which fruit would u like : ");

        scanf("%d", &i);//Enter the fruit number
        if (i <= 0 || i >= 4) {
            printf("\nPlease use the correct number :");
        }
         else {
            printf("Price :%d", a[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your indexing into `a` is always off by 1 - the price of apples is `a[0]` not `a[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

Just define an array of names like

```
int a[3] = { 5,10,15 };
const char *fruit[] = { "Apple", "Orange", "grape" };
```

and use it in a printf call. For example

```
printf( "%s price: %d", fruit[i], a[i] );
```

And these statements

```
printf("1) Apple");
printf("2) Orange");
printf("3) grape");
```

can be rewritten like

```
for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    printf( "%zu) %s\n", i + 1, fruit[i] );
}
```

Take into account that this if statement

```
if (i <= 0 || i >= 4) {
```

is incorrect. There must be

```
if (i < 0 || i > 2) {
```

Also it is a bad idea to use magic numbers.

You could write instead.

```
enum { N = 3 };
int a[N] = { 5,10,15 };
const char *fruit[N] = { "Apple", "Orange", "grape" };

size_t i = 0;

//...

scanf("%zu", &i);//Enter the fruit number
if ( !( i < N ) ) {
```